# выделение директории в python sublime text Anaconda

Tags: python, sublime-text

недавно перешёл на sublime text (установил Anaconda). я часто работаю с файлами, директориями, столкнулся с проблемой, Anaconda выделяет фрагмент директории в белый прямоугольник. и постоянно убирает обратный слэш
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как это настроить?

Comment: при чем здесь анаконда?

Comment: она, же выделяет синтаксис? нет?

Comment: анаконда - менеджер/набор пакетов и окружение. синтаксис выделяет sublime